# How do I sort this file according to the numbers and display it to the readers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this file representing scores:

```
Ishaan - 72
Jack - 84
Bob - 23
Louis - 77
```

So far I have got all of the scores into a single list without all the newline characters:

```py
 # Opening the file
ScoresFile2 = "/Users/KADAM BOYS/Desktop/Ishaan's Folder/Homework (Year 10)/Computing/Mock Project/Scores.txt"

#Editing the scores into a list
ScoresWithNames = [] 

#Appending the scores to a list and removing all the newline characters
with open(ScoresFile2) as file2:
    for line in file2:
        ScoresWithNames.append(line.strip())
```

The list it creates is:

```
['Ishaan - 72', 'Jack - 84', 'Bob - 23', 'Louis - 77']
```

But I do not know how to sort the file according to the numbers.

Comment: Your scores are part of a string. Probably you would like to insert them in a database or in a tuple, alongside the name, in order to split it from the name. That's what *parsing* is all about.

Comment: It is not fully clear what is your final goal. Do you want to sort and write it back to the file sorted in the same format? Or do you want to have a sorted list to work with inside your program? It is important to understand if you wish to keep the strings in the format of `"Bob - 23"` or wish to get a mapping between a name and a score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort the list:

```
l = ['Ishaan - 72', 'Jack - 84', 'Bob - 23', 'Louis - 77']
```

Use:

```
[j[::-1] for j in sorted([i.split(' - ')[::-1] for i in l],key=lambda x: int(x[0]))]
```

Gives:

```
[['Bob', '23'], ['Ishaan', '72'], ['Louis', '77'], ['Jack', '84']]
```

Now to have the ' - ' :

```
[' - '.join(k for k in j[::-1]) for j in sorted([i.split(' - ')[::-1] for i in l],key=lambda x: int(x[0]))]
```

Gives:

```
['Bob - 23', 'Ishaan - 72', 'Louis - 77', 'Jack - 84']
```

Till here, the answer is in ascending order. For a reversed:

```
[' - '.join(k for k in j[::-1]) for j in sorted([i.split(' - ')[::-1] for i in l],reverse = True,key=lambda x: int(x[0]))]
```

gives:

```
['Jack - 84', 'Louis - 77', 'Ishaan - 72', 'Bob - 23']
```

Comment: Thank u so much Joshua Varghese... I have been trying to work out this problem for ages now.

Comment: As a note: this only works if no score is lower than 10 or higher than 99, unless there's zero-padding happening

Comment: @ChatterOne thank you for that debugging. I've solved that and updated by answer

Comment: @ChatterOne is it okay now?

Comment: @Ishaan why retick?

Comment: @Joshua Varghese.... Don't worry about it, I was just wondering if you could tick two answers for the same question.

Comment: @Joshua Varghese...I have posted another question on SO, so you can try to answer it.

Comment: @Ishaan answered :)

Comment: @Ishaan check now, is the answer ok in that question?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to use a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2.2/ref/lambdas.html) function:

```
ScoresWithNames.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(" - ")[-1])
```

Sample test:

```
>>> ScoresWithNames = ['Ishaan - 72', 'Jack - 84', 'Bob - 23', 'Louis - 77']
>>> ScoresWithNames.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(" - ")[-1])
>>> ScoresWithNames
['Bob - 23', 'Ishaan - 72', 'Louis - 77', 'Jack - 84']
```